# Return real duration of select statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

When you perform a SELECT query similar to below in MySQL command line.

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER LIMIT 1000;
```

It returns:

> 1000 rows in set <0.00 sec>

When it clearly takes around 1.5+ Seconds to complete.

Could anyone tell me why this is the case, and even better how to get the real duration?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be network lag? MySQL reports the time it took it to execute the query, exclusive of the time it took to receive the query and to transmit the results... sending 1000 rows over the network could take 1.5s depending on the setup.

Comment: SELECT * FROM MASTER LIMIT 999;
SELECT * FROM MASTER LIMIT 1; 

Weirdly the above does return a good approx time at the command line   but then its not accessible from the profiler.

Answer (score 1):

1.5+ sec means the time it takes to get the rows from database.

You can use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to print active transactions

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on profiling:

`set profiling=1`

then;

`show profile for query...`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html

Comment: This returns the same as command line so doesn't fix it(just with more decimal points). It is the method i have been using for Update and Insert statements which works very well.